# Scikit-Learn failing to install on OS X: undeclared identifier and assignment errors

Tags: scikit-learn

In trying to install scikit-learn on my machine, I'm running into problems. I'm running OS X 10.8.4 with Python 2.7.5 from Homebrew, and I have the latest versions of Scipy and Numpy installed.

I've tried installing scikit-learn via Pip as well as by cloning the latest source and building from scratch- this is what I get every time it tries to build. Any idea what's going on here?

```
1 warning and 3 errors generated.
In file included from sklearn/feature_extraction/_hashing.c:258:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:15:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1728:
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_deprecated_api.h:11:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION"
 ^
sklearn/feature_extraction/_hashing.c:2439:15: error: assigning to 'int' from incompatible type 'void'
    __pyx_t_2 = PyErr_BadArgument(); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_2 == 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[1]; __pyx_lineno = 160; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
              ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
sklearn/feature_extraction/_hashing.c:4833:96: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PyBoolObject'
  __pyx_ptype_7cpython_4bool_bool = __Pyx_ImportType(__Pyx_BUILTIN_MODULE_NAME, "bool", sizeof(PyBoolObject), 0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_ptype_7cpython_4bool_bool)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[4]; __pyx_lineno = 8; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                               ^
sklearn/feature_extraction/_hashing.c:4834:105: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PyComplexObject'
  __pyx_ptype_7cpython_7complex_complex = __Pyx_ImportType(__Pyx_BUILTIN_MODULE_NAME, "complex", sizeof(PyComplexObject), 0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_ptype_7cpython_7complex_complex)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[5]; __pyx_lineno = 15; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                        ^
1 warning and 3 errors generated.
error: Command "cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c sklearn/feature_extraction/_hashing.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/sklearn/feature_extraction/_hashing.o" failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: What exactly are the NumPy and SciPy versions?

Comment: Numpy is at 1.7.1, and SciPy is at 0.12.0.

Comment: This is not the ideal format for discussing bugs, but do you have Cython installed? If not, would you please install it with `pip install cython`?

Comment: Installed cython, same result. I know this isn't ideal, but I thought I'd make sure I wasn't doings something stupid before filing an issue. I'll go do that now, and link to it from here.

Comment: installing Cython doesn't change things; I wanted to suggest you run Cython on `sklearn/feature_extraction/_hashing.pyx`, then recompile and try again.

Comment: OK. Running `pip install cython` seemed to work but whenever I try to run cython (including on _hashing.pyx) it stops with an error saying `ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Scanning.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyCFunction_Check`. Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: beats me, sorry. I don't use a Mac either. I suggest you send a message the scikit-learn mailing list, there are Mac users/devs reading it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same build issue after upgrading to OSX 10.9 Mavericks. I resolved it by running:

```
xcode-select --install
```

to update the XCode Command Line Tools.

I also upgraded all by homebrew libraries with:

```
brew update
brew doctor
# fix all reported issues
brew upgrade
```

I had to uninstall and reinstall some dependencies that were previously built against an incompatible version of the C++ standard library.

Comment: I'm on Mavericks too but when i run ``xcode-select --install``, it says "Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server.". I read somewhere that this is because Command Line Tools is now delivered with Xcode, but I have the latest version 5.0.1 and still it does not work. Reinstalled it and nothing changes, do you know what to do?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. But if you find please report back the solution as a new answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on OSX 10.9 Mavericks, maybe it'll help you on OSX 10.8.4, or in case you upgrade your system in the future. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19592680/2014276) and in further research I learned that you need to install XCode Command Line Tools, which is generally obtained running on terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

If it works, you go directly to the Homebrew step at the end of this answer. However, some users (as myself) may have trouble in running this because Command Line Tools is now delivered with Xcode and not available anymore this way. It'll probably say:

> "Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server."

It turns out that upgrading or re-installing Xcode may not work either, apparently it wasn't delivered for me this way. Fortunately, there's another way of obtaining this Command Line Tools (I read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19547385/2014276)):

1. Open up Xcode
2. In the application menu item "Xcode" select Open Developer Tool > More Developer Tools...
3. This takes you to a site with a bunch of software. Go ahead and download and install "Command
   Line Tools (OS X Mavericks) for Xcode - Late October 2013".
4. If you are not a Mavericks user, you'll find your own version too.

Then you try installing Scikit-Learn again. If it still does not help, Xcode might not be pointing to the right location. You either try this (source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19649139/2014276)):

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

or that (source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19659594/2014276)):

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

The first one with `Xcode.app` is the one that worked for me. And by doing this way, you are certainly preventing another problem you would have with Git command-line broken too, which would bug you in the next and final step: Homebrew. This is because Homebrew depends on Git to work properly.

Homebrew Step:

```
brew update
brew doctor
# fix all reported issues
brew upgrade
```

If still not working, re-install Homebrew ([Homebrew homepage](http://brew.sh/)) and do it again. I hope this will solve your issue :)