# Updated to OSX 10.9, now getting ruby error using homebrew

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

Updated to Mavericks and updated Xcode.  Now I am getting this error when trying to use brew.

```
  $ brew cleanup
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:259: invalid multibyte escape: /^\037\213/ (SyntaxError)
invalid multibyte escape: /^\037\235/
invalid multibyte escape: /^\xFD7zXZ\x00/
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from /usr/local/bin/brew:10:in `<main>'
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: You have to update homebrew, try running `brew update`

Comment: Run `cat -v /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb | head -n1`. It looks like there's a couple special characters on the first line. You can edit them out in, e.g. `vim`. Were you peeking at the source?

Comment: Or look at `/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/module.rb`.

Comment: @Kevin the Regexp contains a sequence that's invalid in UTF-8, it was updated.

Comment: I fixed by changing the symlink of Current Ruby version to 1.8

Comment: Changing the symlink worked for me, too...
`cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions`
`rm Current`
`ln -f -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current`

Comment: Honestly, try not to use system ruby. Give RVM or ruby_env a shot.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to use RVM instead of the system’s Ruby. It has worked wonders for me.

Answer (score -1):

In Mavericks, Command line tools are not available anymore through Xcode.

You can install them from the command line running "xcode-select --install"