# PyCrypto Not Working in OSX Mavericks

Tags: python, macos, osx-mavericks, pycrypto

Trying to install and use pycrypto. I'm not getting any error during installation so I can't troubleshoot further.

I ran 'test' and go following errors but could not find a fix for it.

FYI, I've XCode and Commandline tools installed.

```
mac:pycrypto-2.6.1 rajivvishwa$ export ARCHFLAGS='-arch i386 -arch x86_64'
mac:pycrypto-2.6.1 rajivvishwa$ sudo python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
running build_configure
warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
mac:pycrypto-2.6.1 rajivvishwa$ sudo python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
running build_configure
warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.6.egg-info
Writing /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.6.egg-info

mac:pycrypto-2.6.1 rajivvishwa$ sudo python setup.py test
running test
.......................................................................................................................................................................................................... SelfTest: You can ignore the RandomPool_DeprecationWarning that follows.
build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.6/Crypto/Util/randpool.py:40: RandomPool_DeprecationWarning: This application uses RandomPool, which is BROKEN in older releases.  See http://www.pycrypto.org/randpool-broken
  RandomPool_DeprecationWarning)
..........E...................
======================================================================
ERROR: Test that mpzToLongObj and longObjToMPZ (internal functions) roundtrip negative numbers correctly.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.6/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_number.py", line 283, in test_negative_number_roundtrip_mpzToLongObj_longObjToMPZ
    k = number._fastmath.rsa_construct(n, e)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rsa_construct'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1033 tests in 150.196s

FAILED (errors=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 456, in <module>
    core.setup(**kw)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 336, in run
    SelfTest.run(module=moduleObj, verbosity=self.verbose, stream=sys.stdout, config=self.config)
  File "build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.6/Crypto/SelfTest/__init__.py", line 74, in run
    raise SelfTestError("Self-test failed", result)
Crypto.SelfTest.SelfTestError: ('Self-test failed', <unittest._TextTestResult run=1033 errors=1 failures=0>)

mac:pycrypto-2.6.1 rajivvishwa$ python
Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:29) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Crypto
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Crypto
```

Answer (score 3):

if you run python via macports, try

```
sudo port install py27-crypto
```

then import Crypto should work

Comment: I tried this and it looks like pycrypto is now installed in python2.7 and not in my default python. Can I install in default python with macports?

Comment: no you cannot with macports, macports is for alternative pythons, for default python you should try brew install

Comment: brew is broken for me because of mavericks update. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635804.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install pycrypto on latest OSX then set 'clang' as the C compiler that configure will use. This is done via the CC environment variable.

The way to debug this in a virtualenv:

```
sudo easy_install virtualenv==1.10.1
virtualenv venv
export CC=clang
venv/bin/pip install --no-clean pycrypto
cat venv/build/pycrypto/config.log
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a case insensitivity preference in Mac filesystems. Linux is case sensitive and my guess is that the package owners used Linux to create the package.

I first installed the crypto packages (used `sudo` as last resort).

```
sudo pip install pycrypto

pip install crypto
```

Then just rename the lower case package name to upper case.

In `/path/to/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, rename `crypto` to `Crypto`.