# Can't push Rails App on Heroku since OSX 10.9, gem install pg is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, osx-mavericks, rails-postgresql

Since OSX 10.9, I'm not able any more to push my rails app zu heroku.

Heroku gives the following error:

> ```
>   Failed to install gems via Bundler.  
>   Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
> ```

When I "bundle install", then I get the error:

```
Installing pg (0.17.0) 
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Users/USERNAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/pg-0.17.0/.gemtest
An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

And gem install pg -v '0.17.0':

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Users/USERNAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/pg-0.17.0/.gemtest
```

I tried to install pg via brew, but this doesn't work, too.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: @NickM He is using RVM, you can tell by the path. Seems like some permissions got screwed up in the update. Can you try `sudo -u USERNAME bundle install`

Comment: then i get the output:
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0) among 9 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
from /Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/bundle:18:in `<main>'
from /Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in

Comment: Maybe this question will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539303/troubles-with-rails-and-postgres-after-updating-to-os-x-10-9-mavericks

Comment: Hi, I didn't get it completely: Do you have problems while deploying to Heroku or on your local machine. I don't believe that there's a /Users/USERNAME on Heroku perhaps therefore you receive the "permission denied"?

Comment: @diego.greyrobot I tried that. the result looks like: http://j.mp/I2jAaw
;
fenton I can't bundle locally - so I can't push it on heroku..

Comment: now i was able to update brew and install apple-gcc42. now bundle install runs through, but still: 'Gems in the group pg were not installed.' > 'ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/pg-0.17.0/.gemtest'. How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

did you try to update your gems?
`sudo gem update --system --no-user-install`

Comment: no this doesn't help. Heroku push still tells me: Bundler Output: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

After bundle install: Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the group pg were not installed. But I can install it with "gem install pg"

Comment: Adrian - did you make sure that after bundle you committed and pushed both Gemfile and Gemfile.lock?  
Nizam - right. I'm new here so thx for the feedback :)