# Apache unable to load postgres

Tags: php, apache, pdo, php-pgsql

Today i have updated my MacBook to OS X 10.9.

After the update new configs (httpd.config and php.ini) were added and the old configs was renamed `previous`. I changed the confignames and everything works finde. Everything? No, postgres were not loaded. I created a `phpinfo() test.php` to check this. And yes, postgres were not loaded.

A view into the apache error log say `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function pg_connect()`. This is the logical response.

---

**EDIT:**

I tried the solutions from:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539303/troubles-with-rails-and-postgres-after-updating-to-os-x-10-9-mavericks)
But still the same problem.

I manually installed `PDO_postgres`with pecl. Now `phpinfo()` shows the `pdo_pgsql` extension and apache can load the dynamic library. But i need the normal `pgsql` extension. I still get the:

`PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_pgsql.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_pgsql.dll`

error.

How can i install the normal `pgsql` extensions manually? Pecl don't find the package.

I can successfully connect to my databases with PGAdmin.

---

Do someone know how i can fix the problem? Have i forgot something to change?

**EDIT2:**

I solved the problem with installing `pgsql` extension manually.

Answer (score 1):

I m not very sure about  OS X
but this happens in Windows or Linux usually because the  OS extensions missing

Comment: so should i copy the extensions manually into the extensions folder?

Comment: maybe you can try and do not forget  the php.ini

Answer (score 1):

This Problem is also known and discussed here:
[Enabling PostgreSQL support in PHP on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588174/enabling-postgresql-support-in-php-on-mac-os-x)

Additionally I found an other solution, by using PostgresApp (http://postgresapp.com) instead of Brew here ([Postgres.app, PHP and Mavericks](http://kimsserver.dk/geekstuff/index.php?post/2013/10/22/Postgres.app,-PHP-and-Mavericks))

Hope everything is clear now!

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql seems no longer be part of Mac OSX, but can be easly installed manually e.g. via brew. (http://brew.sh)

This Question / Problem is already known on StackOverflow, just visit
[Repairing postgresql after upgrade to OSX Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565708/repairing-postgresql-after-upgrade-to-osx-mavericks) and fix the problem by installing postgresql via Brew and starting it via launchctl.

Hope that works,

cheers