# git error "unable to locate xcodebuild" after a fresh OS X Mavericks upgrade

Tags: git, xcodebuild, osx-mavericks

When I try to run previously working git commands, I get this:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_intarray_bind
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
git: error: unable to locate xcodebuild, please make sure the path to the Xcode folder is set correctly!
git: error: You can set the path to the Xcode folder using /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 166):

This works for me `sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/`

Comment: I had xcode and another xcode beta. After uninstalling the beta I got "Error: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/otool -L /usr/bin/install_name_tool". Then I did this commando and it works again.

Comment: I did `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app` but that did not solve my problem. Why did your approach solve the problem?

Comment: Dunno how you figured that out, but it worked for me too.

Comment: You have to make sure the command line tools are installed, when I finally upgraded to sierra, these weren't installed - http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I got `xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/'`

Comment: I also got `xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/'`, for me the solution was to just update the XCode app from Appstore. After that it started working.

Comment: I ran into this issue when upgrading Sierra -> Catalina and the command shared by @sushilprj fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 43):

After a much googling and confusion, the following steps lead to a solution (with Xcode installed). Some might be optional, so please feel free to elaborate on this as I am not an expert on these errors.

- download mavericks command line tools https://developer.apple.com/downloads/
- `xcode-select --install`
- `sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`
- `brew install sqlite3`
- commented out `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` entry in my `.bashrc` file

Comment: You don't need to download mavericks command line tools/be a developer. You can start on step 2. (assuming you have the new xcode, at least)

Comment: I'm getting OP's error when trying to install a redmine plugin after updating Command Line Tools to version 6.0 for OSX 10.9.  The key takeaway on this was to run the command `sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` which fixed my error.  Thanks!

Comment: personally i only needed steps 1-3. thanks for this info!

Comment: I only needed step 3

Comment: STEP2 and STEP3 were enough for me

Comment: I upgraded Mac Os X from Mojave to Catalina, and got a similar error when running `git`. I develop in Intellij, not Xcode, but needed the command line tools. The first two commands above resolved this for me.

Comment: I had upgraded to Big Sur 11.6.3 and had the same issue as the original post. My issue was resolved by performing step 2 and 3 just as a few others here. I initially did step 3 only which prompted the error that the path given in step 2 was not an allowed path. Hopefully this helps a few others with similar but not the exact problem.

Answer (score 32):

On MacOS Mojave this worked for me (git 2.21.0):

```
xcode-select --install
sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked on Catalina as well. This is a better answer as the installation (first command) was required.

Answer (score 14):

If you have already installed Xcode, you can run the following command to determine and point to the correct location

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Or use AppStore to install latest Xcode.

Comment: `git` stopped working for me after I updated to Catalina. Updating Xcode in the App Store worked for me. Didn't need to switch anything.

Answer (score 12):

```
xcode-select --install
sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

This did it for me.

Answer (score 9):

Most likely you need to reinstall the command line tools before switching the xcode path to point there.

First install the tools

`$ xcode-select --install`

This will install the tools into the folder `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`.

Then point the xcode path to where the tools were installed, like this

`$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

Note: You can see the current xcode path with the command `$ xcode-select -p`. Mine was initially pointing to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` when I was getting the error

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me in MacOS High Sierra (10.13.6)

sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/

Answer (score 3):

I met this error when i run the command 'git clone xxx'

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Reason: image not found
git: error: unable to locate xcodebuild, please make sure the path to the Xcode folder is set correctly!
git: error: You can set the path to the Xcode folder using /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch

Then, run the command

```
xcode-select -p
```

pointing to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

After run the command
`sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

it points to `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

Answer (score 2):

I hit this same issue running Fastlane on a fresh High Sierra installation.
Solved with:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should install Xcode 5.0.1 for Mavericks. Check updates.

Comment: the problem happens with exactly that config on my computer also

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, just paste in terminal:
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after updating from High Sierra to Monterey. If you just updated MacOS, a simple Xcode update will do. No extra steps are needed.