# How to fix permission/link path on git for OSX

Tags: git, macos

Running OSX 10.4 (Yosemite)

I get this error when I run "git {command}" as a user:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib/libJPEG.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
git: error: unable to locate xcodebuild, please make sure the path to the Xcode folder is set correctly!
git: error: You can set the path to the Xcode folder using /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch
```

When running "sudo git {command}", everything works fine. Not sure what's wrong. I'm guessing it's some kind of install issue, linking issue or permissions issue. Anyone know whats going on/how to fix?

UPDATE:

Following the post listed below, I was able to make git calls without being the root, but am still encountering linking errors:

```
Cloning into 'master'...
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _iconv_open
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/git
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _iconv_open
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/git
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
```

It would seem there's something majorly wrong with the linking here, anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Seems quite similar to this question asked in 2013: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647788/why-is-this-git-command-line-broken-after-a-fresh-os-x-mavericks-upgrade

Comment: Thanks! Followed the instructions but encountered new error, seems to be related to linking still....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `/usr/local/bin` appears in your `$PATH` before `/usr/bin`, so `/usr/local/bin/git` is found before `/usr/bin/git` (`sudo` resets `$PATH` to a predefined value that doesn't generally contain `/usr/local`, so that's why it works). Try and see if `/usr/bin/git` works better for you.

That said, it also appears that `/usr/local/bin/git` is broken. It looks like it was installed by a third party package manager (MacPorts would be my guess).

I would suggest to either just remove it (`sudo port -fp uninstall git`, although I'm unfamiliar with MacPorts and lifted that command line from its documentation, so it may not work) or to try to reinstall it to fix the issues you encounter.