# Running VTK from python (not just vtkpython)

Tags: python-3.x, macos, cmake, vtk

I am compiling and installing [VTK](https://www.vtk.org) (from source) with Python wrappers using my `install_VTK.sh` file (see below).
(I require VTK in order to use [mayavi](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/).
Currently [conda](https://conda.io/) does not have VTK v8.1.0 and a version of mayavi compatible with Python 3.)

Using `install_VTK.sh` VTK successfully complies and installs.

Running the Python wrapper created by VTK:

```
>>> vtkpython -c "import vtk"
```

is successful.

However using the standard python:

```
>>> python -c "import vtk"
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Abort trap: 6
```

is not.

This means that in order to install mayavi successfully I temporarily create an alias `python -> vtkpython` before

```
>>> pip install mayavi
```

and then restore the original `python -> python3.5`.

I believe `python -c "import vtk"` fails because the python library `libpython3.5m.dylib` is not linked in the VTK wrapper files unlike in vtkpython:

```
>>> otool -L libvtkCommonCorePython35D-8.1.dylib 
libvtkCommonCorePython35D-8.1.dylib:
    @rpath/libvtkCommonCorePython35D-8.1.1.dylib
    @rpath/libvtkWrappingPython35Core-8.1.1.dylib
    @rpath/libvtkCommonCore-8.1.1.dylib
    @rpath/libvtksys-8.1.1.dylib
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

>>> otool -L vtkpython
vtkpython:
    @rpath/libpython3.5m.dylib
    @rpath/libvtkWrappingPython35Core-8.1.1.dylib
    @rpath/libvtkCommonCore-8.1.1.dylib
    @rpath/libvtksys-8.1.1.dylib
    /usr/lib/libutil.dylib
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

I believe (please correct me) that this is a result of this [change](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/merge_requests/1511/commits) (to fix this [bug](https://www.vtk.org/Bug/view.php?id=16068)) to allow VTK to use compatible Python versions that are installed in different locations from what was used in the initial build.

**I would like to know if it is possible to force the inclusion of `@rpath/libpython3.5m.dylib` when calling `cmake`.**

---

The common suggestion is

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH":<path>/.miniconda3/envs/testVTK/lib"
```

but apparently this is considered bad practice and fails anyway:

```
 vtkpython -c "import vtk"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path>/.miniconda3/envs/testVTK/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vtk/vtkRenderingFreeType.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .vtkRenderingFreeTypePython import *
ImportError: dlopen(<path>/.miniconda3/envs/testVTK/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vtk/vtkRenderingFreeTypePython.so, 2): Symbol not found: _sqlite3_intarray_bind
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
  Expected in: <path>/.miniconda3/envs/testVTK/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<path>/.miniconda3/envs/light-3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vtk/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .vtkRenderingFreeType import *
  File "<path>/.miniconda3/envs/light-3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vtk/vtkRenderingFreeType.py", line 9, in <module>
    from vtkRenderingFreeTypePython import *
ImportError: dlopen(<path>/downloads/VTK-8.1.0/vtkBuild_3.5/lib/vtkRenderingFreeTypePython.so, 2): Symbol not found: _sqlite3_intarray_bind
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
  Expected in: <path>/.miniconda3/envs/light-3.5/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
```

Strangely it also looks back to the build dir:

```
ImportError: dlopen(<path>/downloads/VTK-8.1.0/vtkBuild_3.5/lib/vtkRenderingFreeTypePython.so, 2): ...
```

---

## Install File: `install_VTK.sh`

This is the file I created to build and install VTK

```
# -- input data --
# The directory path of the extracted download of VTK
VTK_DIR=VTK-8.1.0

PY_VER=3.5

MAIN_PATH=/path/to/python/environment/.miniconda3/envs/testVTK

PY_LIB=libpython${PY_VER}m.dylib
PY_INC=python${PY_VER}m

QMAKE_PATH=${MAIN_PATH}/bin/qmake
CMAKE_PATH=${MAIN_PATH}/bin/cmake

# -- move into dir --
cd ${VTK_DIR}

BUILD_DIR=vtkBuild_${PY_VER}
mkdir ${BUILD_DIR}
cd ${BUILD_DIR}


CMAKE_OPTIONS="
-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:PATH=${CMAKE_PATH} \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${MAIN_PATH} \
-DCMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH:BOOL=ON \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH:PATH=${MAIN_PATH}/lib \
"

# specify the installation of Python
# https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/module/FindPythonLibs.html
PYTHON_OPTIONS="
-DVTK_PYTHON_VERSION:STRING=${PY_VER} \
-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:PATH=${MAIN_PATH}/bin/python${PY_VER} \
-DPYTHON_LIBRARY:PATH=${MAIN_PATH}/lib/${PY_LIB} \
-DPYTHON_LIBRARIES:PATH=${MAIN_PATH}/lib/${PY_LIB} \
-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=${MAIN_PATH}/include/${PY_INC} \
-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=${MAIN_PATH}/include/${PY_INC} \
-DVTK_INSTALL_PYTHON_MODULE_DIR:PATH=${MAIN_PATH}/lib/python${PY_VER}/site-packages \
"
# deprecated
# PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH
# PYTHON_DEBUG_LIBRARIES

# -- additional options --
CC=cc
CXX=c++

ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS="
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=${CC} \
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${CXX} \
-DVTK_REQUIRED_OBJCXX_FLAGS:STRING='' \
-DVTK_USE_CARBON:BOOL=OFF \
-DVTK_USE_COCOA:BOOL=ON \
-DVTK_USE_X:BOOL=OFF \
-DVTK_USE_TK:BOOL=OFF \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release \
-DBUILD_DOCUMENTATION:BOOL=OFF \
-DVTK_HAS_FEENABLEEXCEPT:BOOL=OFF \
-DBUILD_TESTING:BOOL=OFF \
-DBUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF \
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON \
-DVTK_WRAP_PYTHON:BOOL=ON \
-DModule_vtkRenderingMatplotlib:BOOL=ON \
"

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HDF5_OPTIONS="
-DVTK_USE_SYSTEM_HDF5:BOOL=ON \
"
MPI_OPTIONS="
-DModule_vtkParallelMPI:BOOL=ON \
"
#mayavi needs version 4
QT_OPTIONS="
-DVTK_QT_VERSION:STRING=4 \
-DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:PATH=${QMAKE_PATH} \
-DVTK_Group_Qt:BOOL=ON \
"
EXTENSION_OPTIONS=$HDF5_OPTIONS$MPI_OPTIONS$QT_OPTIONS
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

OPTIONS=$CMAKE_OPTIONS$PYTHON_OPTIONS$ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS$EXTENSION_OPTIONS

cmake $OPTIONS ..

# -- build --
# make with max number of logical cores
make -j $(sysctl -n hw.logicalcpu_max)

make install
```

---

## System

- Mac 10.13.2
- [VTK 8.1.0](https://www.vtk.org/download/)
- cmake 3.10.0
- Python 3.5 (Miniconda)
- Additional python versions are also on the system (2.7, 3.6)

---

Comment: The line you have posted starting with `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` looks suspicious. There should not be a space between signs `=` and `$`. Moreover, `<path>` should be substituted by the path of the proper directory (probably sth like `/Users/username/`).

Comment: I use `<path>` here just as an abbreviation. I will correct the typo with the space. Thanks. :)

Comment: So in your system you put everything properly? I don't understand why after you had modify DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, vtkpython stopped working. Have you tried suggestion given in [cmake wiki](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling)? BTW, your problem is not so rare. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647788/git-error-unable-to-locate-xcodebuild-after-a-fresh-os-x-mavericks-upgrade).