# clang: error: unable to locate xcodebuild

Tags: c, xcode, macos, macos-high-sierra, command-line-tool

I am using a mac version 10.13.6.

I want to compile C programs through the terminal. I've downloaded Xcode and the command line tools. When I type `clang --version` in the terminal, I get the following two error messages:

> clang: error: unable to locate xcodebuild, please make sure the path to the Xcode folder is set correctly!
>
> clang: error: You can set the path to the Xcode folder using /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch

I did some googling and found a fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31780545). The solution is to run the following line in terminal:

`sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Which I did. But when I enter `clang --version` after doing this, I get exactly the same two errors. What's going on?

NB: very very new to this so please keep that in mind when answering! cheers

Comment: What made you use `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` instead of `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/`?

Comment: Because that directory doesn't exist in my computer. Initially I looked for that. But then I tried typing xcode-select -p (which I found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/15371967), which returns /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer.

Comment: I just tried what you said and it worked! I have no idea why. But thank you!

Comment: Things have changed over time.  You could try `xcode-select --install`; that may do the job for you. Sometimes, running the XCode GUI will download and install some extra software. With XCode 10.0, you may need to install the extra package mentioned in [Can't compile C program on a Mac after upgrade to Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509602/cant-compile-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrade-to-mojave) — which isn't directly your problem since you're still using macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra, but it may still be relevant. Read the XCode 10 release notes (link in the answer); they may help.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for this. I recently updated to Mojave and this was very useful!

Answer (score 13):

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

worked like a charm for me